# 'Software Updates Installed' keeps appearing regardless of updates

Tags: updates, 22.04, notification

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, and for about a month or two I've been having this really silly issue. Every time I turn my PC on, I get a notification that says 'Software Updates Installed. Important OS updates have been installed'. Other threads I've seen about those popups are from people wanting to disable them completely, and I don't want to do that. I just want to get notified when there have been some actual updates. Right now the popup appears regardless of what's been installed or not and it happens no matter how often I reboot. Any idea how to set this straight?

Comment: These annoying persistent pop-up notifications will disappear by themselves eventually if you ignore them. You might have to wait a few months though.

Comment: @karel incredible. Is this a snap thing?

Comment: I have the fuzzy idea of firmware-update.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yes, it's a snap thing.

Answer (score -1):

These reoccurring pop-up notifications will stop being sent to your desktop by themselves eventually if you ignore them. You might have to wait a few months though. The pop-up notifications that I got on my system were all to inform me that one or more of my snap packages had been updated. These pop-up notifications didn't bother me, so I didn't even click to close them and let them disappear from my desktop by themselves. Eventually I stopped getting them altogether.

Comment: So basically I'm waiting for someone to patch it up?

Comment: Patching it up would be great, but I didn't patch it up it and it went away by itself after a few months without breaking anything anyway.

Comment: Strange. But thanks anyway